# how to set multiple initstyle to stage javafx

Tags: javafx

i have tried to set multiple `initstyle` but it can`t be happen

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED,StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

I also tried

```
 primaryStage.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but it gives an error

so how can I set my primary stage to be undecorated and transparent

basically in Java I can set

```
frame.undecorated(true);
frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

and that would do the trick

how to do that in javafx then ?

please explain i am new to javafx. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` already creates a undecorated window, therefore there should be no need of using 2 `StageStyle`s. You probably just didn't change the default `fill`/`background` of the `Scene` and your root pane.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

creates a stage that just shows a button.